# How can we get all of the indexes values inside the $config variable from a specific custom config file?

Tags: codeigniter, config, codeigniter-3, custom-configuration

I have created a config file named email.php inside application/config folder. Now I want to assign my variable `$email_config` to all the indexes of the $config variable inside my email.php config file.

I have tried to use `$email_config = $this->config->config;` but this will get all the indexes values of $config variable from every config files under the config folder..I don't want that, I only want the indexes values inside my email.php file

Comment: `$this->config->config`: this approach doesn't exist in CI, could you please try to explain better what you are trying to achieve? Please read about the [CI Config Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html)

Comment: @Vickel This is not entirely true, approx. 10 years ago the full config was still available in this way.

Comment: @Vickel I found that solution from a old post in stackoverflow..not sure how it works, but it just worked hahahaha